# Python Web Scraping Get the main content only

Tags: python, text

```
import numpy as np
import json 
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2017/03/06/518805720/turkey-germany-relations-at-new-low-after-erdogan-makes-nazi-comparison"

html = urlopen(url)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')


def keyInfo(div):
  print(div.find("h1").get_text())
  print(div.find("span", {"class":"date"}).get_text())
  print(div.find("a", {"rel":"author"}).get_text().strip())
  print(div.findAll("p")) # Problem here

keyInfo(bsObj)
```

The problem is the last line in def keyInfo, it prints lot of things, tags, captions, I only want the main content the texts, how I can achieve that?

Comment: Please revisit how to ask a [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on Stack Overflow so your question is well received by the community. Furthermore, please ensure you are familiar with how to put together a [MCVE]. Keep in mind, that help is given here for explicit problems with programming issues in the problem you are trying to solve. As is, this is too broad as you haven't given nearly enough information for the readers to be able to effectively help you.

Comment: Revised, is this clear enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code extracts that particular site's content a little better.

```
def keyInfo(div):
  print(div.find("h1").get_text())
  article = div.find("article")
  divText = article.find("div", id="storytext")
  [a.extract() for a in divText.findAll("aside")]
  [d.extract() for d in divText.findAll("div")]
  print(divText.get_text())
```

### Approach

After looking at the structure of the content using Chrome dev tools, I noticed the story content was in `article > div[id=storytext]`, but `div[id=storytext]` also included a few asides and divs with non-article content. Removing those left the paragraphs of the article.

### Looking for something a little more generic?

If you're looking for something a little more generic, you may want to consider something like Boilerpipe. Here is a Python wrapper for Boilerpipe: https://github.com/misja/python-boilerpipe

Comment: Works well, I only modified the last line:  `code`print(divText.get_text().replace('\n',""))